# Configuring different hostnames for IIS sub-aplications

Tags: iis, localhost, hosts

I'm having few applications under DefaultWebSite on IIS pointed to the same source code and distinguished by aliases:

```
localhost/app1
localhost/app2
localhost/app3
```

Is it possible to configure different hostnames for each app via windows hosts file? For example, to have them like this:

```
app1.localhost
app2.localhost
app3.localhost
```

I needed it to test a single sign-on feature and to be sure that auth cookie isn't shared inside the same domain(localhost)

Comment: I think I have to configure URL rewrite on IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should modify the hosts file and url rewrite rule to achieve your requirement.

Firstly ,you should go to the hosts file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) and add below settings.

```
127.0.0.1   app1.localhost
127.0.0.1   app2.localhost
127.0.0.1   app3.localhost
```

Then you could add below url rewrite rule into the web.config to rewrite appx.localhost to localhost/app1.

```
            <rule name="cio">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).localhost" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/{C:1}/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```